# How to extend Constructor Injection?

Tags: dependency-injection, service-locator

Suppose I have `MyClass` with a very simple dependency.  It uses constructor injection.

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    private IA A;

    public MyClass(IA a)
    {
        A = a;
    }
}
```

This code get shipped and some other developers are using it.
At some point in the future I need to add in a second dependency, on IB.

**How should I add this dependency on IB?**

Some options, and why I disapprove:

- Just add it to the constructor

  - Braking change.
- Inheritance or the decorator pattern.

  - Extra classes and code bloat.
  - New class will have boilerplate code passing around the IA.
  - I have no guarantee that other developers will switch to using the new class.
- Use a service locator to populate the new IB field.

  - I'm now using two different types of injection for extra confusion.

It seems to me that constructor injection is just not easily extensible.

Comment: If you just add a new field via the constructor, then that doesn't seem to add any value. You will only add a new field or dependency if it is being used. Which means you'd also have to change the code itself to use the new dependency.

Comment: Adding a *required* dependency is a breaking change, no matter how you inject that dependency.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, wouldn't say it needs to be a breaking change. For example, if I write `private IB B = new B();`, doesn't break anything. Only when we try to use constructor injection do we see a breaking change.  Do you agree?

Answer (score 3):

1. Create an implementation of `IB` that contains whatever behavior `MyClass` currently possesses that is being extracted, or if `IB` provides new functionality, then a sensible default implementation that preserves `MyClass`'s current semantics.
2. Add `IB` dependency to `MyClass` via a new constructor.
3. Have the old constructor create an instance of the implementation of `IB` you made in *step 1*.

Old code still works, new code can provide alternate behavior as desired.

Comment: So you are saying, create an "empty" implementation of IB, which the old contructor can use?

Comment: A couple of reasons why I'm not 100% happy with this solution.  1) Code bloat of this empty class.  2) I have no guarantee that other developers will switch to using the new non-empty class.

Comment: Isn't a “guarantee developers will switch” the definition of breaking change?

Comment: The implementation doesn't have to be empty. I don't know what you're trying to do so I don't know what constitutes a sensible default implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If `MyClass` *needs* to have an `IB` to function, then there is not really a choice.
Any non-breaking change would just results in bugs because the others will keep using `MyClass` without providing the required `IB` object, so you can just as well prevent that and make the new dependency a required parameter of your constructor.

If the dependency on `IB` is *optional*, then you have a few options:

- Derive a new `MyClass_version2` from `MyClass` and provide all the new `IB`-related behavior from there. This will likely work best if there is little overlap between the existing behavior and the extensions.
- Add the new `IB` dependency to `MyClass`, but ensure to set it to `null` in the existing constructor and ensure that all methods can handle a null `IB`. Then add an overload of the constructor `MyClass(IA a, IB b)`.